# JS reading of inputs into dynamically created HTML form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, field

Help sought;

I've been playing around with code snippets from here and there that dynamically add text fields to an HTML form. The page is basic: a form prompts for at least one text field input; has a button to offer to add more text fields; has a button to submit the entries in all fields that were presented - the idea is that field entries are read into variables then simply displayed to the user by the same html page.

The addition of fields to the form works ok.

What I cannot figure out is how to read inputs made into the fields, using just JS in the same page (i.e. there is no PHP or other server based reading of the data).

Extract from the code, that creates the additional fields is as below:

```
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
            <div><input type="text" name=mytext[]></div>
        </div>
```

and the portion of the JS used to dynamically add fields appears as:

```
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name=mytext[]/><a href="#" class="remove_field">x</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});
```

then, the forms "submit" button is as follows:

```
<input name="button" onclick="addtext()" type="button" value="Show" />
```

then, the function (in the same page) addtext() is basically:

```
   function addtext() {
       var f2 = document.myform.?????????????
       document.writeln(f2,'<br>')
    }
```

where the "?????????????" represents an attempt to read the entry from any of the mytext[] dynamically added fields....this is the part I cannot figure.

Suggestions appreciated.
Thx.

Comment: Read the values in the same page, in a different page - after form submission? In what function? What does this function do, how far have you got with it? When should the values be available, as soon as they're entered or before you submit the form - after clicking the 'submit' button or whatever?

Comment: - the idea is to read the form inputs, in the same html page

Comment: - the form has a input type button, which calls a function addtext() - the idea of the function is to simply read the fields inputs into variables (e.g. var f1 = document.form.field.value) - and then the function simply calls document.writeln() to display those variables. Basic idea is - present form with option to add input fields, read those fields when submit is clicked, show those entries to user.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the details there, that way they're not buried in - ephemeral - comments that are prone to being ignored, unread and/or deleted at any time. Also, while you're adding details, try and clarify the question as you go to make it readable and complete. When doing so bear in mind that this is all we know of your situation, we don't know anything else. So try and work out, from the information you provide, if *you* could understand the question if you didn't know anything more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost got it through.

```
var readInputVariables = function(){
  $('input:text').each(function(index,element){
      console.log(element.val()); // do whatever you want with the value;
  })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*[the OP has] almost got it through*" - he's not shown any code that attempts to read the `<input />` elements' values or, as yet, described from what point the (currently hypothetical) function should attempt to read the values. Also the `input:text` selector is less efficient than `input[type=text]` (since it has to use Sizzle, rather than the native `document.querySelectorAll()`).

Comment: The issue is simply with reading the mytext[] field entries - what is the simplest construct for that? var f = document.myform.mytext[].value ?